# How to get ClientCertificate from the request (comparing ASP.NET and Silverlight)

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, silverlight-4.0, x509certificate

I have a Silverlight Web Application which uses Silverligh-enabled WCF service for getting datas from other Web-Services and Database. In the previous, end users signing in to the web  site by writing their UserName and Password to the TextBoxes and clicking button. Now, end users have a card and a card reader. Certification prompt must be appeared after entering the web site. So, I have changed my web service and it uses HTTPS. And in IIS I set SSL Settings to Require for the Web Site. Of course, I have created Web Site certificate also and set the binding's certificate to it. Everything works fine now. The web site and the web service are opening with HTTPS. Also, certification prompt is displaying whenever entering to the Web Site. And after all certificates are shown in the list, user must choose one of them. After that he must enter his password and if data in the certificate store is same with the card in card reader, the webSite is opening.

I have read [this](http://sladapter.blogspot.com/2011/10/steps-to-make-silverlight-enabled-wcf.html) article for configuring web Service to use HTTPS.

In ASP.NET we are getting certificate like that:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);
string subject = Request.ClientCertificate.Subject;

if (!Request.ClientCertificate.IsValid || Request.ClientCertificate.Count == 0)
{
     // failed
}
else
{
     Session["isRegistered"] = true;
     // success
}
```

But I dont know how to get certificate from the request with Web Service.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that, I have solved the problem. I sent ClientCertificate property of request object from Asp.net to Silverlight like that:

```
      <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
        <div id="silverlightControlHost">
            <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
              ...
              <param name="initParams" 
value="ClientCertificate=<%=Request.ClientCertificate.Subject %>, cc=true, m=/relative" />
              ...
        </form>
```

And in App.xaml.cs I am getting values in Application_startup event:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.InitParams != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.InitParams)
                {
                    this.Resources.Add(item.Key, item.Value);

                }
            }

            this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what the best option for you would be to implement a custom Certificate Validator for your service. This is basically a class that derives from [X509CertificateValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.x509certificatevalidator.aspx) and is then [registered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347699.aspx) through the config file.

There's more complete information on how to do this on [this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx)

Comment: What is the purpose of Validator? My problem is, I can not get certificate which are choosed by User  from the certification prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the security context of the WCF request in the System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current object, especially in the ServiceSecurityContext field.